# LibGit2Sharp filter-branch like capabilities

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am looking to use LibGit2Sharp to write code to support a scenario we want to automate.
We want to create a new git repo from specific folders in an existing git repo while still providing history for the migrated folders.

So given:

`sourcRepo/
   folderA/
   folderB/
   folderC/`

And if we choose folderB and folderC, then we want a new repo like the following:

`newRepo/
   folderB/
   folderC/`

*Where newRepo has the full history of changes for folderB and folderC.*

How can this  be accomplished in LibGitSharp2?